# Scroll JScrollPane while dragging a JLabel that is on that JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jlabel

I have multiple JPanels placed onto a JScrollPane. Right now I have it so that if your mouse is outside of the frame then it will not drag the JPanels.

I need to make it scroll while I moving the component in a direction. (ex. If I grab component and then move to the right all the way to edge of screen the component should move and the JScrollPane should scroll at the same time). Essentially both should be visible while I am dragging and while JScrollPane is (autoscrolling?)

```
int dX,dY;
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    dX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - this.getX();
    dY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - this.getY();
}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    this.scrollRectToVisible(getVisibleRect());
    this.setLocation(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - dX, e.getLocationOnScreen().y - dY);
    dX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - this.getX();
    dY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - this.getY();
}
```

Thats the code for the dragging. The screen (which is a variable) is a JPanel which is what is being sent to the JScrollPane which is contained in a JFrame.

Comment: Please explain your problem in greater detail. Assume that we know nothing of your project.

Comment: sorry. tried to clear it up a bit. not still sure if you get it.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it's me, but there are still way too many unknowns for me to understand the issue. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrollPaneView.setAutoScrolls(true) together with your scroll-to-visible code should work.

See JComponent#setAutoscrolls javadoc for more information.

Comment: +1 for `setAutoScrolls()`; see also [`ScrollAction`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513).

Comment: set autoscrolls on the label that is being dragged or on the whole panel?

Comment: Depends on which component you installed your mouse listener.