# Binding events between JComponent and ComponentUI delegate

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, events

I have started trying to create normal MVC Swing components. I have no problems with M and C, but V had thrown at me one problem which I cannot normally solve.
The problem is: Controller is main class of the component (MyComponent, for example), and it extends JComponent. View is ui delegate (MyCompanentUI) extended from ComponentUI class. All what delegate does is adds JTextField in MyCompanent and provides data binding between MyComponentModel and this field. It works just fine. But how I can bind events from JTextField to MyComponent?
If user wants to handle some events he adds listeners to MyComponent, but all real events (mouse, focus, keys, etc.) intercepted by JTextField, about which user does not really knows.
So is there any normal way to do this, except catching events and translate it to original component by hands? Or is there another way to create delegate and I just really do it all wrong?

UPD:

Thanks for your response, trashgod.
But I had something different in my mind. I was talking about something like "events inheritance", like in the case of "inheritsPopupMenu" method. So that then key, focus or mouse event happens to the component one does not process it itself, but directly transfer it to parent component. But it seems impossible, because I have noticed JSpinner has exactly the same issue - you cannot get almost any event notification from this very component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing your own `JComponent` subclass and want to allow for custom UI delegates, I'd start with Kirill Grouchnikov's [*How to Write a Custom Swing Component*](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html).

If you are writing a composite that includes an existing `JComponent` subclass, such as `JTextField`, see if you can leverage the existing `Action` instances described in [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). [`ScrollAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513) is an example. You can learn the names of such actions from the component's source(s) or using [@camickr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) handy utility seen in the article [*Key Bindings*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

Comment: In the specific case of `JSpinner`, you can register a listener on the `SpinnerModel`. More generally, you can use a similar [architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).