# JScrollPane in JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wonder if you guys had problem such if you got some `JPanel` which got his own `JScrollPane` and in your panel you are using a lot of `JTable`s with their own `JScrollPane`s, there is a problem to scroll up/down your panel?

I mean when your mouse is on viewport of some table, then `JScrollPane` of `JTable` is listening on scroll, so when I got many `JTable`s I am able to scroll only in a few places of the panel, it's so annoying...

Are there some functions which will send my scroll event to parent `JPanel` `JScrollPane` when the `JTable` scroll is even not shown? I mean I want to disable `JScrollPane` whenever some `JTable` don't need to use scroll (when it is hidden, cause there are too less records).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `JTable` understands several named scrolling [actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), listed below. They are normally used in [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), but you can evoke them yourself, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513) that commandeers the actions defined for a scroll pane.

Addendum: In outline, get the named action from the component's action map:

```
Action action = table.getActionMap().get(name);
```

Evoke the action by name when needed:

```
action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(table, 0, name));
```

Scrolling related action names for `JTable`:

```
scrollDownChangeSelection
scrollDownExtendSelection
scrollLeftChangeSelection
scrollLeftExtendSelection
scrollRightChangeSelection
scrollRightExtendSelection
scrollUpChangeSelection
scrollUpExtendSelection
```