# Change ENTER Key function

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

I wanted to change the default action of the ENTER key on `JTable`, so I used this code:

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
table.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //my action
    }
}
```

Tt works normally. What I want now is to change the row just after my action. In other words, execute the default action of the enter key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is `"selectNextRowCell"`. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20413603/230513), you can obtain a reference to the original `Action` and evoke in your new handler.

```
String name = "selectNextRowCell";
Action action = table.getActionMap().get(name);
…
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(table, ActionEvent.ACTION_FIRST, name));
}
```