# Reassign a Windows key to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

How can you reassign a windows action to a key combination in Java? I want to basically share the default windows 'Page Down' action to a key combination such as 'control D'.

This is what I have so far:

```
KeyStroke addedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control D");
getInputMap().put(addedKeyStroke, "page-down");
```

However, nothing happens when I press ctrl-L. Please could someone let me know what needs to be done to get this working?

Thanks,

Comment: Mmm you just edited like i answer it.. did you put `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, WHEN_FOCUSED, WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`

Comment: Just trying that now, will let you know. Thanks

Comment: In what component are you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
KeyStroke addedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control D");
InputMap inputMap = myTable.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
inputMap.put(addedKeyStroke , "scrollDownChangeSelection");
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20413603/2415194)

Comment: Im afraid none of those options seem to work. I'm trying in a JTable

Comment: I have just managed to fix this. Used 'WHEN_FOCUSED' and changed the 3rd line to:         inputMap.put(addedKeyStroke, "scrollDownChangeSelection");

Comment: @maloney great! you got it i provide a link with a trashgod answer!  you should provide your own answer i'll upvote you!