# Swing Action with JTree

Tags: java, swing, action, jtree

As developing a Swing application I use `Action` rather than `Listener`. I have an action which is usually triggered from `AbstractButtons` but now I need to trigger it as well when selecting a `JTree` node.

Since the `TreeSelectionModel` does not support Actions I am wondering what the best practice would be to archive this.

Until now I just came up with the idea to implement a generalized method which is invoked from `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` and as well from `addTreeSelectionListener(TreeSelectListener)`.

Anyone who has a better idea?

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: @alex2410 That's a rather generic question with no concrete implementation behind, yet.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it might increase coupling between your `TreeModel` and its view component, `JTree`. As [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instances are often used in [*key bindings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it may help to review the existing actions defined for common Look & Feel implementations, as shown in @camickr's article [*Key Bindings*](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). These actions can be evoked from your [`TreeSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html), as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513) that leverages scroll pane actions.

Addendum: For reference, `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel` defines these `JTree` actions and bindings.

```
Action                        Focused                                             Ancestor
------                        ------                                              -------
addToSelection                SPACE
cancel                                                                            ESCAPE
clearSelection                ctrl BACK_SLASH
collapse                      SUBTRACT
copy                          ctrl INSERT, ctrl C, COPY
cut                           CUT, shift DELETE, ctrl X
expand                        ADD
extendTo                      shift SPACE
moveSelectionTo               shift ctrl SPACE
moveSelectionToParent
paste                         shift INSERT, ctrl V, PASTE
scrollDownChangeLead          ctrl PAGE_DOWN
scrollDownChangeSelection     PAGE_DOWN
scrollDownExtendSelection     shift ctrl PAGE_DOWN, shift PAGE_DOWN
scrollLeft                    ctrl LEFT, ctrl KP_LEFT
scrollLeftChangeLead
scrollLeftExtendSelection
scrollRight                   ctrl RIGHT, ctrl KP_RIGHT
scrollRightChangeLead
scrollRightExtendSelection
scrollUpChangeLead            ctrl PAGE_UP
scrollUpChangeSelection       PAGE_UP
scrollUpExtendSelection       shift PAGE_UP, shift ctrl PAGE_UP
selectAll                     ctrl SLASH, ctrl A
selectChild                   RIGHT, KP_RIGHT
selectChildChangeLead
selectFirst                   HOME
selectFirstChangeLead         ctrl HOME
selectFirstExtendSelection    shift HOME, shift ctrl HOME
selectLast                    END
selectLastChangeLead          ctrl END
selectLastExtendSelection     shift END, shift ctrl END
selectNext                    DOWN, KP_DOWN
selectNextChangeLead          ctrl DOWN, ctrl KP_DOWN
selectNextExtendSelection     shift ctrl DOWN, shift DOWN, shift ctrl KP_DOWN, shift KP_DOWN
selectParent                  LEFT, KP_LEFT
selectParentChangeLead
selectPrevious                KP_UP, UP
selectPreviousChangeLead      ctrl UP, ctrl KP_UP
selectPreviousExtendSelection shift UP, shift KP_UP, shift ctrl UP, shift ctrl KP_UP
startEditing                  F2
toggle
toggleAndAnchor               ctrl SPACE
```